# How to resolve AssertionError in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, assertion

I am currently working on a project in Selenium in Python and I am getting `AssertionError` when I put a specific parametrised value `6.00` in the parentheses.

**Test.py**

```
Class Test:

def test_voidnewcard(self):  
    np.createReqNewCard(expected_price= 6.00)
```

**NewCard.py**

```
Class NewCard:

def createReqNewCard(self, expected_price):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.jobOrder_xpath).send_keys(self.jobReqNewCard)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.excelButton_xpath).send_keys(self.excpath)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.topup_textbox_xpath).send_keys("1")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.calculateAmount_xpath).click()
        subTotalAmt =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]").text
        totalCalAmt =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/label[1]").text.replace("Total amount: $", "")
        assert subTotalAmt == totalCalAmt == expected_price, "Price mismatch! Expected price is %s, subtotal is %s, total price is %s" % (round(expected_price,2), subTotalAmt, totalCalAmt)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.buttonSubmit_xpath).click()
        time.sleep(8)
```

**Error StackTrace(If I put `6.00` as the parametrised value**

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\testCases\AutoTest.py", line 77, in test_voidnewcard
    np.createReqNewCard(expected_price= 6.00)
  File "C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\newCard\NewCard.py", line 29, in createReqNewCard
    assert subTotalAmt == totalCalAmt == expected_price, "Price mismatch! Expected price is %s, subtotal is %s, total price is %s" % (round(expected_price,2), subTotalAmt, totalCalAmt)
AssertionError: Price mismatch! Expected price is 6.0, subtotal is 6.00, total price is Total Amount: $6.00
```

**Error StackTrace(If I put `"6.00"` as the parametrised value)**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\testCases\AutoTest.py", line 77, in test_voidnewcard
    np.createReqNewCard(expected_price='6.00')
  File "C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\newCard\NewCard.py", line 29, in createReqNewCard
    assert subTotalAmt == totalCalAmt == expected_price, "Price mismatch! Expected price is %s, subtotal is %s, total price is %s" % (expected_price, subTotalAmt, totalCalAmt)
AssertionError: Price mismatch! Expected price is 6.00, subtotal is 6.00, total price is Total Amount: $6.00
```

Can someone solve this issue? I just can't seem to diagnose this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realised that the text has a special character so I cannot convert to `float`

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Total Amount: $6.00
```

so the value of `totalcalamt` is

```
Total Amount: $6.00
```

therefore I should use

```
float(subTotalAmt.split('$')[1])
```

This get only the numerical part of the `string`.

Answer (score -1):

`text` property returns string even if text looks like a number. `"6.00"` is not equal to `6.00`. Try

```
subTotalAmt =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]").text
totalCalAmt =  [float(i) for i in self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/label[1]").text.split() if i.isdigit()][0]
assert float(subTotalAmt) == totalCalAmt == expected_price
```

Comment: Why is that so? I tried tweaking the parameter by tweaking it to `6.000` but to no avail.

Comment: @TechGeek49 do you mean code still fails?

Comment: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: Total Amount: $6.00`. I'm getting this when I initialise the `expected_price` parameter = `"6.00"`

Comment: it looks like the replace method is not being run for totalCalAmt

Comment: so what should I do then?

Comment: @TechGeek49 instead of `text.replace` try `totalCalAmt =  [float(i) for i in self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/label[1]").text.split() if i.isdigit()][0]`

Comment: Could you mind updating the soln to ur existing sln? It's difficult to reformat it